# Help with fixing a Coq installation using docker and vscoq

Tags: coq, installation

I'm following the logic foundation preface and just began learning. I tried to use the docker with vscoq like the suggested in the book but it didn't work for me and kept asking me to install coq again, so I installed it using opam but then I had this error:

```
Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path ImpCEvalFun with prefix LF
```

If anybody could help I tried to fix it all night yesterday.

Comment: Is the error message the title of your question, by any chance?

Comment: yes it is if you could help me I still didn't find a solution

Comment: That error means that the file `ImpCEvalFun.vo` can't be found. That's the compiled version of the `ImpCEvalFun.v` file. That is one of the last chapters of Logic Foundations though. Can you interact with `Basics.v` as expected? What about with `Induction.v`? That is [where the book explains how to compile files](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Induction.html). If my comment is not helpful, please update your question with information about what exactly you did before obtaining the error message.